# Override default attributes' value of HTML "a" tag which was set by FB js library

Tags: javascript

I have an example of old facebook share button where i want to change href attribute of link tag. I used below piece of code but unable to change its href value. Can anyone suggest why it's not working?

```html
<a id="shareMe" name="fb_share" type="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share Me</a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("shareMe").href="javascript:alert('hi');";
</script>
```

Comment: Have you found some error log in browser console?

Comment: Yeah i found below text. Thanks.
  
##########################
#  The endpoint used to load this resource has been deprecated.
#  Please update to the current Facebook JavaScript SDK.
#  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
##########################

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to consider.

1. This api is deprecated, which you may be aware of, though functionality is still there.
2. The `a tag` with an id of **shareMe** is replaced with FB's HTML so, the href will not exist.

Inspect the element and you will see that the HTML is not even an `a tag` anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/5awey/

Comment: Please select this as the answer if this is the answer to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. Just to be curious, how can i select an element using jquery that is generated within iframe through code in question? Let's say how can i select the `a` tag with class `pluginShareButtonLink`?